# Loading an image in a JAR

Tags: java, image

At the moment I am trying to load images in a way that will be "JAR friendly" so-to-speak, but I am having trouble getting it the images to load.

Currently the folders are laid out as such:

```
>src
  >package.name.etc
    ImageLoader.java
>assets
  >images
    >menu
      background.png
```

At the moment I am trying to implement the following code:

```
    public Image loadImage(String filename) {
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = this.getClass().getResource("assets/images/menu/" + filename);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Image i = tk.getImage(url);
        return i;
    }
```

and in another method where I am trying to load the image:

```
Image background = loadImage("background.png");
```

This simply returns a null pointer exception stating there is no image there, and I am really not sure how to the correct directory for the image to work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: This is the error I get, and I am not sure where I should be catching it from.

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using Maven or not ?

Comment: Can you please show the stackstrace of your error ?

Comment: Make sure your asset folder is in the class path.

Comment: Not using Maven. Added the error. In the class path? Then how would I go about making it so it can stay in the current structure?

Comment: right click the image in eclipse and select properties, copy the full specified path and try using that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"/assets/images/menu/"` (/ before assets)?

Comment: try moving `assets` inside src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to include in the jar an image, I have done the following steps :

1. Use the following hierarchy:

   src>

   packageName <--- code is here

   packageName.resources <--- image structure here
2. Configure the build path to include packageName.resources
3. Get the Image with the following code :

---

```
try {
    BufferedImage img = 
        ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/"+filename));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Comment: This solution is not strictly necessary: you are not forced to put assets in child folders of the code that calls them.

Comment: Although I have tried it without changing the directory structure and just putting .....getResourceAsStream("/menu/images/" + filename); and it gets that image from the assets folder without needing to change the directory at all. So it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and check if the `assets/images/menu/` part is needed